# How to map dictionary with entity as key and class with corresponding user type as value?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following property in one of my entities:

```
IDictionary<SomeOtherEntity, IPcmStream> PropName { get; set; }
```

`SomeOtherEntity` is obviously another entity that is mapped to the database.
`IPcmStream` is an interface for which an implementation of `IUserType` exists. This implementation maps the interface to a `byte[]` column. It is activated for all occurrences of `IPcmStream` using an `IUserTypeConvention`.
Now, how do I map this property using Fluent NHibernate?

I tried it like this:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.PropName).AsMap("SomeOtherEntity_id");
```

But that leads to an exception stating that `IPcmStream` is an unmapped class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.PropName)
    .Table("Linktable")
    .AsEntityMap("SomeOtherEntity_id")
    .Element("PcmStream_id", e => e.Type<MyUserType>());
```

AsEntityMap tells NH that the Key of the dictionary is a mapped entity and you give it the column for the id of the entity. Element says that the Values are simple Elements and the custom type is converting from column "PcmStream_id" to the type

Comment: Boom! It works. Thanks a lot. :-) I will never understand dictionary mapping in FNH...